# What does 「の元に」mean in this sentence?「白銀会長の元に 承認リクエストが送られます」

Tags: grammar, words

This line is from Kaguya-sama: Love is war

> 白銀会長の元に 承認リクエストが送られます

What does 「のもとに」mean in this sentence?

From my understanding of the context, the characters were talking about how to send a follow request to a twitter account, but I don't know how 「のもとに」affects the meaning of the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to someone's side or location. In this case it means the request arrives at his *location*. My understanding is it suggests that the request will be delivered, but whether he does anything with it or not is a different story. That is, it's guaranteed to get as far as his door but no further.

It's a subtle difference, but contrast this with 「白銀会長<del>の元</del>に～」. Here I think we can say he 1)personally receives the request, 2)almost certainly acknowledges its presence, and 3)most likely will at least go as far as opening/reading it.

I can't tell whether this is intentional, akin to saying "don't get your hopes up", or if の元に was simply used to be more "technically accurate" about the way requests work and we shouldn't read into it any further.